# Change the background colour of the whole line

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to realise the sidebar of a normal editor: when we hover on one filename, the whole line changes to a darker background colour.

However, given the filenames are listed by `<ul>`, the following code only changes the background colour for `<li>`, does anyone know how to change the background colour for the whole line where the hover is?

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/koseriyose/1/edit?html,output)

```css
.sidebar {
  width: 102px;
  background-color: #f3f3f3
}

li:hover {
  background-color: #cccedb
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, yes, it is possible, `list-style-position: inside;` does just that.

Comment: Yep, you're right - good solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the whole line is changed. The problem is the default padding on the `ul` element, if you remove that you can see what happens. You now have to add `list-style-position: inside;` to keep the bullets inside if you need. You can also add `padding-left: 20px;` to the `li` element to get in the same position like when you had padding on `ul`. See the snippet below please:

```css
.sidebar {
  width: 102px;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
li{
  padding-left: 20px;
}
li:hover {
  background-color: #cccedb;
}
ul{
  padding: 0;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You could add `ul li { padding-left: 20px; }` to retain the original spacing too

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, yes, you are right, updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
.sidebar ul{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
 }
 .sidebar ul li{
  padding: 5px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the bulletin and padding.

add this to `ul`

```
list-style-type:none;
padding:0px;
```

```css
.sidebar {
  width: 102px;
  background-color: #f3f3f3
}
ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0px;
}
li:hover {
  background-color: #cccedb
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `<ul>` has a padding as default, which causes that spacing left to those bullet. If you want, you can override that behavior by removing the bullet and the spacing. This is done by setting the `padding` to 0. Then if you want to keep the bullets, you can use `li:before` and add a bullet as content. The unicode of the bullet `•` is `'\2022'`. Then add some `margin-right` and there you go.

I have used `.sidebar ul` as selector because if you use only `ul` as selector, then all lists in the document is being affected. It might be not your goal. `.sidebar ul` means that the `<ul>` element in an element with the class name "sidebar" is being selected to apply these rules.

```css
.sidebar {
  width: 102px;
  background-color: #f3f3f3
}

li:hover {
  background-color: #cccedb
}

.sidebar ul {
  padding: 0;
}

.sidebar li:before {
  content: '\2022';
  margin-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul, li{
  padding:0px;
   /* you need to remove default padding of ul */
}
.sidebar {
  width: 102px;
  background-color: #f3f3f3
}

li:hover {
  background-color: #cccedb
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```